# Failing to clip vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip, overlapping-features

I have a vector layer which has lines (rivers) from a watershed and I want to clip the layer with the polygon of the watershed. I have tried clip, intersect, so on, so on. But I get error msgs.

Even if I ignore invalid input features, I can’t clip it. How can I complete this geoprocess? Is it possible? I want only the lines of the river layer falling within the watershed.

I checked that both layers have the same EPSG. I tried by selecting the “no filter” option and I get a msg that simply says, intersection failed at such time. It says that some features have invalid geometry. When I select the “skip invalid geometry” option, I get a msg about no index and although it completes the clipping process, it comes out empty.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error msgs. Did you check the projections of both layers? Do they have the same EPSG Code?

Comment: @eurojam is correct, we would like tot see more details about your input data and those *errors* that occur.

Comment: Try *Fix geometries* processing tool, then clip

Comment: Is the watershed actually a polygon?